# how can I link a list to another list using a third one?, works sometimes but bugs when this happens

Tags: python, list

I'm working on a small personal project where I turn a d&d story into a game.
I ran into a problem when the story reaches a point where a sheep runs to the character with the highest magic , and since I generate magic randomly at the start of the session , sometimes two characters can have the same magic value so I give it to the character with the highest charisma between the ones with the highest magic .. since I'm a beginner I tried to solve this with lists, a solution with dictionaries would be much appreciated but that's not my question, I came up with a solution that seems logical to my nooby eyes but if more than one character have equal charisma(regardless of magic values) the code fails and chooses randomly.
here is the code , what would be very useful is if I knew where the code bugs and why
since its completely invisible to me .
`

```
magic=[]
charisma=[]
ttt=["Khablan","Gadaan","El-Armoty" ,"Kulayb",'Zaafaran']
def attributeassigner(ww):
   for x in ttt:
       ww.append(random.randrange(1, 10))
   return ww
print(attributeassigner(magic))
print(attributeassigner(charisma))
def maxfinderassigner(ba):
    o=[k for k,x in enumerate(ba) if x == max(ba)]
    return o
def anychooser(dodo):
    e=ttt[dodo.index(max(dodo[t]for t in maxfinderassigner(magic)))]
    return e
print(anychooser(charisma))
```

`

Comment: What does `baba` refer to in `o=[k for k,x in enumerate(baba) if x == max(ba)]` ?

Comment: ah sorry edited it .. it's ba

Comment: Can you provide an example of output generate by the script where you expected something else (and provide an example of what you expected), or where you get an error message you don't understand?

Comment: [8, 2, 9, 7, 5]
[5, 8, 8, 3, 4]
Gadaan , this is the bug .. gadaan have 2 magic but gets chosen over el-armoty who have 9 magic

Comment: the code works most of the time .. it even works sometimes when charisma results match

Comment: and when it doesn't work it just randomly choose like this .. no errors .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
max(dodo[t]for t in maxfinderassigner(magic))
```

computes the maximal charisma among characters with maximal magic. Then, however, you are searching for a character with this maximal charisma in a list of all characters - not necessarily the ones with maximal magic.

Comment: I can't reproduce such an issue. Do you have an example?

Comment: [2, 1, 2, 3, 3]
[8, 7, 9, 9, 2]
El-Armoty .. elarmoty 2 magic 9 charisma while there are 2 charachters with 3 magic .. i think you might be right but why would it work most of the time tho .

Comment: As I wrote, you are not picking a character with the maximal charisma overall. You are computing the maximal charisma among characters with maximal magic, and then you are picking the first character with that charisma. In your example above Elarmoty has the biggest magic 9. His/her charisma is 8. So you are selecting the first character with charisma 8.

Comment: [7, 8, 1, 9, 4]
[7, 5, 1, 7, 9]
Khablan .. this is an example where it ignored both the highest magic and highest charisma .. and chose the first guy .

Comment: This is the same story. The highest magic is 9, end the corresponding charisma is 7. Thus you are selecting the first character on the list with charisma 7, which happens to be Khablan.

Comment: ooooooh .. that makes sense

Comment: After you generate the magic and charizma lists add two lines: `cm = list(zip(magic, charisma))` and  `ttt[cm.index(max(cm))]`, remove the rest,  and it will work fine.

Comment: man .. thank .. you .. sooooo .. muchhhhhhh

Answer (score 1):

This should fix the problem. It'll first check if there is someone with the highest magic. Then, it will check for someone with the highest charisma. If there are characters with the same amount of both, `Tie` will be returned.

```
import random

magic = []
charisma = []
ttt = ["Khablan","Gadaan","El-Armoty" ,"Kulayb",'Zaafaran']

def attributeassigner(ww):
   for x in ttt:
       ww.append(random.randrange(1, 10))
   return ww

print(attributeassigner(magic))
print(attributeassigner(charisma))

def anychooser():
    if magic.count(max(magic)) == 1:
        return ttt[magic.index(max(magic))]

    if charisma.count(max(charisma)) == 1:
        return ttt[charisma.index(max(magic))]

    return "Tie"

print(anychooser())
```

Comment: The changes i made are in the `anychooser` function

Comment: thank you for the answer i really needed the answer for this as well .. but the bug happens when this happens (for some reason) .. but also happens when two characters have the same charisma regardless of the magic they have .

Comment: @Amado Hmm. I'm not sure I understand what you want the code to do. Would you like it to prioritize choosing the character with the most charisma first or would you like to prioritize choosing the character with the most magic? Which is more important?

Comment: i want to choose the character with the highest magic then if two characters or more have the same max magic i take a list of their indexes and apply it to charisma then take the highest among them and find his corresponding name

Comment: @Amado I just updated my answer